# Cant allocate memory using MALLOC

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, wininet, dynamic-memory-allocation

Can anyone help me as what is going wrong here?
Am not able to allocate memory using malloc...

```
    bReadFile = ReadFile( hConsoleFile, &ReadFileBuffer, MaxCharToRead, &CharsRead, NULL );
```

Comment: How big is the file? How much memory do you have?

Comment: What happens when you try to run that code?

Comment: We need more details-- are you getting a compile-time error (an error when you run the compiler) or a run-time error (an error when you run the program?) What is the text of the error message?

Comment: I get a <Bad Ptr> in my ReadFileBuffer...the file is just 35 chars which dwFileSize reads perfectly.

Comment: malloc usually fails because it cant allocate enough memory. Set a breakpoint or print the value of dwFileSize and make sure you have enough Memory to allocate it. 

Try allocating a static amount and reading the file in chunks if the file is large.

Comment: Actually it does not throws any error and successfully goes to the next method. But the ReadFileBuffer fails to read anything inside the File. Then I debugged it and saw the problem with ReadFileBuffer as <Bad Ptr>. Is this the correct way to assign malloc for BYTE data types?

Comment: I have set a breakpoint and saw the dwFileSize in debug mode that it reads perfectly the size of File.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `&ReadFileBuffer` in the call to [`ReadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You are supposed to pass `ReadFile` a pointer to the buffer, not a pointer to a pointer to the buffer.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
lpBuffer [out]
    A pointer to the buffer that receives the data read from a file or device.
```

Since `ReadFileBuffer` *is* a pointer to the buffer, that's what you should be passing.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for [`ReadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is this:

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadFile(
  __in         HANDLE hFile,
  __out        LPVOID lpBuffer,
  __in         DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  __out_opt    LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  __inout_opt  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

The second parameter should be a pointer to your buffer, not a pointer to a pointer to your buffer.  That's what you got when you did `&ReadFileBuffer`.  The call should be:

```
bReadFile = ReadFile(hConsoleFile, ReadFileBuffer, MaxCharToRead, &CharsRead, NULL);
```